# Change IPSec IKEV2 VPN Default Ports 500 & 4500 To Anothers

Tags: port, centos-7, strongswan

For some reason OpenVPN is working on my local machine very well, But IPSec IKEV2 VPN not & it only works when OpenVPN is connect.
I have a domain for IPSec IKEV2 VPN & in local machine vpn is using port 443.
Tell what should i do to force vpn workable on my local machine without OpenVPN.
Should i change port 443 on server or change ports 500 & 4500?

---

I followed the link below for setup IKEv2 VPN Using Strongswan and Let's encrypt on CentOS 7 With Some Changes.

[How to Setup IKEv2 VPN Using Strongswan and Let's encrypt on CentOS 7](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-setup-ikev2-vpn-using-strongswan-and-letsencrypt-on-centos-7/)

My Let's encrypt commands is like this :

```
curl https://get.acme.sh | sh
~/.acme.sh/acme.sh --set-default-ca --server letsencrypt
~/.acme.sh/acme.sh --register-account -m helius.dev@gmail.com
~/.acme.sh/acme.sh --issue -d my_domain.com --keylength 4096 --standalone --force
service httpd stop
~/.acme.sh/acme.sh --issue -d my_domain.com --keylength 4096 --standalone --force

Your cert is in: /root/.acme.sh/my_domain.com/my_domain.com.cer
Your cert key is in: /root/.acme.sh/my_domain.com/my_domain.com.key
The intermediate CA cert is in: /root/.acme.sh/my_domain.com/ca.cer
And the full chain certs is there: /root/.acme.sh/my_domain.com/fullchain.cer

~/.acme.sh/acme.sh --installcert -d my_domain.com --keylength 4096 --key-file /root/private.key --fullchain-file /root/cert.crt

service httpd start
service httpd status
```

Certificate Copy :

```
sudo cp /root/private.key /etc/strongswan/ipsec.d/private/
sudo cp /root/cert.crt /etc/strongswan/ipsec.d/certs/
sudo cp /root/.acme.sh/p02.artemis-art.buzz/ca.cer /etc/strongswan/ipsec.d/cacerts/
```

StrongSwan config :

```
#global configuration IPsec
#chron logger
config setup
    charondebug="ike 1, knl 1, cfg 0"
    uniqueids=no

#define new ipsec connection
conn hakase-vpn
    auto=add
    compress=no
    type=tunnel
    keyexchange=ikev2
    ike=aes128-sha1-modp1024,aes128-sha1-modp1536,aes128-sha1-modp2048,aes128-sha256-ecp256,aes128-sha256-modp1024,aes128-sha256-modp1536,aes128-sha256-modp2048,aes256-aes128-sha256-sha1-modp2048-modp4096-modp1024,aes256-sha1-modp1024,aes256-sha256-modp1024,aes256-sha256-modp1536,aes256-sha256-modp2048,aes256-sha256-modp4096,aes256-sha384-ecp384,aes256-sha384-modp1024,aes256-sha384-modp1536,aes256-sha384-modp2048,aes256-sha384-modp4096,aes256gcm16-aes256gcm12-aes128gcm16-aes128gcm12-sha256-sha1-modp2048-modp4096-modp1024,3des-sha1-modp1024!
    esp=aes128-aes256-sha1-sha256-modp2048-modp4096-modp1024,aes128-sha1,aes128-sha1-modp1024,aes128-sha1-modp1536,aes128-sha1-modp2048,aes128-sha256,aes128-sha256-ecp256,aes128-sha256-modp1024,aes128-sha256-modp1536,aes128-sha256-modp2048,aes128gcm12-aes128gcm16-aes256gcm12-aes256gcm16-modp2048-modp4096-modp1024,aes128gcm16,aes128gcm16-ecp256,aes256-sha1,aes256-sha256,aes256-sha256-modp1024,aes256-sha256-modp1536,aes256-sha256-modp2048,aes256-sha256-modp4096,aes256-sha384,aes256-sha384-ecp384,aes256-sha384-modp1024,aes256-sha384-modp1536,aes256-sha384-modp2048,aes256-sha384-modp4096,aes256gcm16,aes256gcm16-ecp384,3des-sha1!
    fragmentation=yes
    forceencaps=yes
    dpdaction=clear
    dpddelay=300s
    rekey=no
    left=%any
    leftid=@my_domain.com
    leftcert=cert.crt
    leftsendcert=always
    leftsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
    right=%any
    rightid=%any
    rightauth=eap-mschapv2
    rightsourceip=10.15.1.0/24
    rightdns=1.1.1.1,8.8.8.8
    rightsendcert=never
    eap_identity=%identity
```

And here is secrets file :

```
nano -K /etc/strongswan/ipsec.secrets

: RSA "private.key"
test : EAP "123"
```

---

Let explain problem again.
Some firewall rules on my wi-fi internet provider are blocking vpn (ikev2 - l2tp - pptp)
But openvps works like a charm.
When openvpn is working i can connect to ikev2 vpn by upper config.
Tell me what should i change about ikev2 to work whithout openvpn.
Fist step i think i should chanage ports 500 & 4500 on server.
I am right?
But how?
**/etc/strongswan/ipsec.d/** This file has no place for define custom ports!!!